# Variation under constraint

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations

I always can't compute right.$u=u(x),R=R(x)$ and $\tau$ is constant, and $M$ is compact manifold.If $u$ is the minimizer of 
$$
\inf\{\int_M [\tau(4|\nabla u|^2+Ru^2)-u^2\ln u^2-nu^2](4\pi\tau)^{-n/2dV} 
~~|~~\int_M u^2(4\pi\tau)^{-n/2}dV =1  \}
$$
,how to compute the Euler-Lagrange of 
$$
\int_M [\tau(4|\nabla u|^2+Ru^2)-u^2\ln u^2-nu^2](4\pi\tau)^{-n/2dV} 
$$
under the constraint 
$$~~\int_M u^2(4\pi\tau)^{-n/2}dV =1$$

> In my book ,the answer is 
>   $$
> \tau(-4\Delta u+Ru)-2u\ln u-nu=\mu u
> $$
>
> $\mu$ is defined as below.
>   $$
> \mu=\inf\{\int_M [\tau(4|\nabla u|^2+Ru^2)-u^2\ln u^2-nu^2](4\pi\tau)^{-n/2dV} 
> ~~|~~\int_M u^2(4\pi\tau)^{-n/2}dV =1  \}
> $$

No matter how I compute it , only $\mu$ I always can't got. I want an detail answer ,so thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's Lagrange multiplier. Whenever you want to maximize $F$ subject to $G = 1$, then at the minimum $u$ there is $\mu$ so that $\nabla F = \mu \nabla G$. In your answer 
$$
\tag{1} \tau(-4\Delta u+Ru)-2u\ln u-nu=\mu u,
$$
the left hand side is $\frac 12 \nabla F$, where 
$$F(u) = \int_M [\tau(4|\nabla u|^2+Ru^2)-u^2\ln u^2-nu^2]dV$$
and the right hand side is $\frac 12 \nabla G$, where 
$$G(u) = \int_M u^2dV. $$
Since you have assumed that $u$ is the minimum, by multiplying $(1)$ by $(4\pi\tau)^{-n/2}u$ and then integrate over $M$ (and use integration by part), you have 
$$\begin{split}
\mu&= \int_M\mu u^2 (4\pi\tau)^{-n/2}dV \\
&= \int_M [\tau(4|\nabla u|^2+Ru^2)-u^2\ln u^2-nu^2](4\pi\tau)^{-n/2dV} 
\end{split}$$
which is the same as the minimum you want.

Comment: Merry Christmas.

Comment: My result is $\frac{1}{2}\nabla F= \tau(-4\Delta u+Ru)-2u\ln u-nu-u$.There is a redundant $u$.

Comment: Do you have idea about this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518259/curvature-of-given-metric-space   ?

Comment: I really think there are a little question.$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{t=0}F(u+tv)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{t=0}\int_M [\tau(4|\nabla (u+tv)|^2+R(u+tv)^2)-(u+tv)^2\ln (u+tv)^2-n(u+tv)^2]dV=\int_M[\tau(8\nabla u\cdot\nabla v+2Ruv)-2uv\ln u^2-2uv-2nuv]dV
$